# PHP mySQL not letting me insert into a table

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I'm using the code:

```
function insertV($deptx, $coursex, $secx, $isbnx,$titlex, $authorx,$usedpx,$newpx)
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO `$deptx` (`course`, `sec`, `isbn`, `title`, `author`, `usedp`, `newp`) 
VALUES ('$coursex','$secx','$isbnx','$titlex','$authorx','$usedpx','$newpx')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

}

$dept = "ACCOUNTG";
$course = "340";
$sec = "101";
$isbn = "9780324651140";
$title = "FINANCIAL ACCOUNTING";
$author = "STICKNEY";
$usedp = "$129.75";
$newp = "$199.75";
insertV($dept,$course,$sec,$isbn,$title,$author,$usedp,$newp);
```

But I keep getting an error:

> Warning: mysql_query(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource in
>   /home/public_html/mysite.com/myscript.php
>   on line 14 Error:

I'm guessing it has to do with me trying to access a table using a var?

Any help would be appreciated, I'm still new to PHP if you couldn't tell :P

EDIT: Oh yeah, line 14 is

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't defining your `$con` within the function. This is part of PHP's scoping rules. Variables defined outside a function are not visible within a function unless you declare them `global`, you'd need something like this:

```
function insertV(...) {
    global $con;

    $query = "...";
    etc...
}
```

So, the error is due to $con being null within the function, which is "not a valid MySQL-link resource"

Answer (score 6):

The error means that the connection you're providing to `mysql_query` (`$con`) is not a valid MySQL resource. `$con` is never defined in your function anywhere. You want to open a connection before querying, like so:

```
$con = mysql_connect("[mysql server hostname]", "[mysql username]", "[mysql password]");
```

If you have already created a connection to your MySQL server outside of the function, you can import the global $con variable by adding `global $con;` at the top of your function (see [variable scope](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in the php docs if you'd like some more information).

Alternately, the connection resource is an optional parameter in all the mysql functions, so you can just use `mysql_query(...)` (without specifying the connection), and PHP will use the last connection opened by `mysql_connect`.

Comment: +1 for connection being an optional parameter in mysql_query()